# NodeJS express-session how to store data in cookie

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, redis, jwt

Is it possible using express-session to store additional data in the cookie other than just the session ID?

I am considering using the `express-session` module to store session data in Redis. The module appears to have many useful capabilities required for session management such as creating the cookie and managing the session in the Redis store. It would be very helpful to not have to re-implement that functionality.

However, only the session id is stored in the cookie that is created. That makes sense to minimize the size of the cookie, but in this architecture for this app, the cookie that is generated must contain a JWT. A JWT needs to be stored in the cookie because it is going to be used to access other APIs as part of a larger system.

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

> "Note Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session
> ID. Session data is stored server-side."

Is it possible to store the jwt in the cookie? Or, do I need to just write custom methods from scratch to manage the sessions instead of using the express-session module?

Here is the example code from the documentation... is it possible to add additional data to the cookie?

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```